# How can we Share Computer Screen on Internet?

Tags: web, open-source

Is it possible to share computer screen with someone else over internet ?
I have attended few sessions of IBM where the presenter has shared his computer screen with the participants !

How should i go about to include this feature in my project. Any open-source API available to do the same ?

Comment: I don have any idea about open source API.But screens can be shared using TeamViewer and Skype.

Comment: It's possible. check https://join.me/ or http://www.screenleap.com/

Comment: What did you already look up/research/try?

Comment: Should just download this, Shek. It's pretty cool. https://join.me/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options when it comes to screen sharing. Wikipedia has a nice table [comparing lots of remote desktop software.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)

One that looks fairly promising is FreeRDP. The source is on github and it seems to be pretty active project.

If you want to learn more, you can search for info about the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) which is what is being implemented in many of these programs.

If you are looking for something more web-specific (like Chrome's remote desktop), check out [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). It is what the Chrome team is using to accomplish their screen sharing.

Comment: You can share team viewer or remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being limited to Chrome:

[Chromoting (Chrome Remote Desktop)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Remote_Desktop) - *[Chromoting API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromotingBuildInstructions)*
[Google Hangouts](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/) - *[Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/)*

Answer (score 0):

Skype also has a fantastic function for sharing screens.  It allows an entire screen during a phone call for free.  Makes working with someone on a project incredibly easy.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for an API to do this, not a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

Go with TeamViewer, you can share your Computer Screen.

Else Go with Skype, share screen, Video calls etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I Personally like http://join.me
Its fast, small and easy to use.

Will hardly take few seconds to set-up!